# Point 404 pages to homepage

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

I would like to build a website where all page URLs point to the homepage.

Wordpress already shows URLs like

```
website.com/randomstring/
```

as a 404 page. However, instead of the 404 error, I would like it to just show the homepage, while maintaining the URL in the browser's address bar.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So basically you still have a 404 server error but with a front page template. You could copy all `front-page.php` content inside 404.php. Don't forget to check if you have any enqueue that is specific for front page, and add a `is_404()` check as well

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2:**
You could also make a function to load your front-page.php template for 404 pages. See below:

```
add_filter('template_include', function($template) {
    if ( is_404() ) {
        return locate_template(['front-page.php']);
    }
    return $template;
});
```

**EDIT:**
I read over the fact that you want to keep the URL as is. Why is that if I may ask?

You could make a redirect from your 404 page to your homepage. Just edit (or create if it doesn't already exists) your `404.php` file within your theme or child-theme folder. Below snippet redirects all 404's to your homepage:

```
<?php

header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");

header("Location: " . get_bloginfo('url') );

exit();

?>
```

I usually don't recommend this, but I'm going to assume you have a good reason for it.